# IronXSLT download? xmllab.net is offline

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xslt, plugins

Does anyone have the installer for IronXSLT?

xmllab.net seems to have gone down and never revived

http://www.xmllab.net/Products/IronXSLT/tabid/187/Default.aspx

http://74.125.113.132/search?q=cache:jk_L4-aOCi8J:www.xmllab.net/Products/IronXSLT/tabid/187/Default.aspx%3FPageContentID%3D52+ironxslt&hl=en&ct=clnk&cd=13&gl=us&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's mirrored by Brothersoft:

> http://www.brothersoft.com/ironxslt-download-181062.html

Answer (score 1):

Now that Oleg is working for Microsoft perhaps IronXSLT was rolled into this:

http://www.visualstudiogallery.com/ExtensionDetails.aspx?ExtensionID=a6a4ab2b-89aa-45ab-bbbf-3e84ce44af82

now called: XSLT Profiler Addin

Comment: No, the XSLT Profiler is something completely different.